# Pandas/Python: Groupby and transform against a reference table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Target Table with two types of categories: stationID and Month. I need to standardise the Temperature values of that table against the values of another Reference Table (by matching the stationID). What would be the best way to do that with pandas?

For example:

- Reference Table: it contains mean and standard deviation reference values for unique stations

  ```
    stationID | Temp_mean   | Temp_std |...
    ----------+-------------+----------+
    A         |     30.0    |  3.4     |   
    B         |     31.1    |  4.5     |
    C         |     24.5    |  0.2     |
    ...
  ```
- Target Table: it contains the raw data for each station and month

  ```
    stationID | Mon  | Temperature |...
    ----------+------+-------------+
    A         |  1   |     30.1    |    
    A         |  2   |     31.2    |  
    A         |  3   |     24.0    |  
    B         |  1   |     30.3    |  
    C         |  2   |     20.4    | 
    C         |  1   |     24.3    |  
    C         |  2   |     25.4    |  
    ...
  ```

So, from the temperature values in the Target table, I need to subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation of the reference table.

What I have so far is the code below

```
df['Temperature_Stdized']=df(['stationID','Mon'])['Temperature'].transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
```

But, instead of using the mean and std from "x", I would like to use the values from the Reference Table, by matching the stationID values.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your `Reference Table` to be `ref` and `Target Table` to be `tar`, you could do:

```
tar['Temprature'] = (ref.merge(tar, on = 'stationID')
                        .eval('(Temperature - Temp_mean) / Temp_std'))

   stationID  Mon  Temperature
0         A    1     0.029412
1         A    2     0.352941
2         A    3    -1.764706
3         B    1    -0.177778
4         C    2   -20.500000
5         C    1    -1.000000
6         C    2     4.500000
```

**Details**

The first step is a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) of both dataframes on `stationID`:

```
x = ref.merge(tar, on = 'stationID')
print(x)

    stationID  Temp_mean  Temp_std  Mon  Temperature
0         A       30.0       3.4    1         30.1
1         A       30.0       3.4    2         31.2
2         A       30.0       3.4    3         24.0
3         B       31.1       4.5    1         30.3
4         C       24.5       0.2    2         20.4
5         C       24.5       0.2    1         24.3
6         C       24.5       0.2    2         25.4
```

and then [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.eval.html) with the following expression to normalise each row:

```
x.eval('(Temperature - Temp_mean) / Temp_std')

0     0.029412
1     0.352941
2    -1.764706
3    -0.177778
4   -20.500000
5    -1.000000
6     4.500000
dtype: float64
```